# Why is the max size of a std :: string object is 4611686018427387897?

Tags: c++, string, stl, stdstring

I have code where I output the max length of a `std::string` object:

```cpp
string s;
cout<<s.max_size()<<endl;
cout << INT_MAX << endl;
cout<<LLONG_MAX<<endl;
```

**Output :**

```
4611686018427387897
2147483647
9223372036854775807
```

If it's not difficult, please explain why the maximum size of `std::string` is 4611686018427387897. This is approximately half of `LLONG_MAX`.

Comment: Hint: check the type of `std::string::max_size()`

Comment: "*please explain why the maximum size of `std::string` is ...*" - because that is what the implementation decided it should be. If you want to understand the WHY, ask the vendor that wrote the implementation.

Comment: It's also purely a _theoretical_ "max size", as any string near that size would be _millions of consecutive terabytes_.

Comment: As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size - "Returns the maximum number of elements the string is able to hold due to system or library implementation limitations" so the exact value is an implementation detail. Also this value isn't very useful for most applications.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how `basic_string` is implemented in the standard library that you are using. Different implementations may "use" a bit from the size of the string for other purposes (for example, a flag that says "this is a short string").